# Ignoring /etc/aliases with mailx

Tags: alias, email

Is it possible to ignore the alias expansion with mailx? I'm trying to get something sent with a null message body and don't want it to take the local username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the man page it is not possible as it is not implemented.

But you could try `sendmail -f "<>"` to send mails with a null sender. Please note that with most mail servers the `sendmail` is an alias to their equivalent. It is not said to really use *the* `sendmail` of sendmail.

(I assume that your requirements are to send with a "null sender" and not with a "null message body")

Answer (score 0):

You may want to "masquerade" the sender email and name... so:

Here's an answer from 2018, on Debian 9 stretch.

Note the `-e` for echo to allow newline characters, and `-r` for mailx to show a name along with an outgoing email address:

```
$ echo -e "testing email via yourisp.com from command line\n\nsent on: $(date)" | mailx -r "Foghorn Leghorn <sender@yourisp.com>" -s "test cli email $(date)" -- recipient@somedomain.com
```

Hope this helps!